# Limit the depth of generated examples in a Swagger document, or disable the examples

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Is it possible to limit the depth of generated examples, or at least disable examples for a particular endpoint?

An OData controller's action may return `IQueryable`, so it makes sense to use a real EF Core entity in `[ProducesResponseType]` to avoid code duplication:

```cs
public class FooController
{
    [ProducesResponseType((int) HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(List<FooEntity>))]
    public IQueryable GetFooQueryable()
    {
    }
}
```

The problem: the generated example describes nearly the whole database because of navigation properties in the entity, making the entire JSON cumbersome (10MB for example) and almost unusable. Moreover, the example can be just incorrect due to OData `$expand` option is usually configured with the upper limit for nesting, disabling uncontrolled reading of nested entities. This depth is 2 by default.

BTW, I [asked the same in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore repo](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/615#issuecomment-607423819) with no response.